# Terminate established tcp connection using iptables

Tags: networking, scripting, iptables

I have an open socket connection, and I want to close it immediately if packet passing through contains certain string. I have tried the following using iptables:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1342 -m string --algo bm --string ".." -j REJECT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1342 -m string --algo bm --string ".." -j DROP
```

But none of this works, it just freezes connection permanently. How to "cut" the connection permanently?

Note: as a testing application I have used simple netcat. Firstly, I connected client and listener, then sent the string containing forbidden one. After that, no response was received and no more lines could be sent over this connection, even when REJECT rule was used.

Comment: When you reject a packet a response is sent indicating this. When you drop a packet no response is sent. Most likely the application you are using does not know how to handle the former, and might have a very long timeout (often in the order of minutes) for the latter, to allow for really slow and unreliable network connections. Which application are you trying to control?

Comment: @l0b0 as a testing application I have used simple netcat. Firstly, I connected client and listener, then sent the string containing forbidden one. After that, no response was received and no more lines could be sent over this connection, even when REJECT rule was used.

Answer (score 1):

This I hope does the gig for you. Use REJECT with tcp-reset:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1342 -m string --algo bm --string ".." -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Try kmp if not worked:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1342 -m string --algo kmp --string ".." -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Comment: Actually, it does not terminate Netcat listener

Comment: Updated my answer. Try kmp as well.

Comment: it does not work as well. TCP connection does not reset. Tried with `Netcat` and python's `SimpleHTTPServer` now.